# Why is source_gist function in R devtools package not working?

Tags: r, devtools

I run this:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library('devtools')
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/hadley/6872663")
```

I get this:

```
Error: client error: (403) Forbidden
```

Why?

Comment: For me I get `Error: client error: (404) Not Found` but haven't read any of the documentation.

Comment: I get these errors too and workaround them with the raw github page, eg. `source("https://gist.github.com/hadley/6872663/raw/c053eafa78e9399f50d8ab5e0bfae314f07637d1/hi.r")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a bug( some regular expression problem), As a workaround :

```
source_url("https://gist.github.com/hadley/6872663/raw/hi.r")

SHA-1 hash of file is 54f1db27e60bb7e0486d785604909b49e8fef9f9
[1] "Hi from github :)"
```

Comment: will you take care of reporting it?